# passing data from controller to model class mvc-5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model, asp.net-mvc-5, controller

I want to pass the data from controller to my modal class.

Here is a test example of what I want to do,

I can't publish my code here as my code is very large in number of lines.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult testdata()
{
    string testdata = "send test data";//this data i want to pass to my model class
    return View();
}
```

as my modal class is inserting the same data into database

```
public bool inserttestdata()
{
    cmd = new SqlCommand();
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@test", "test data want here");//here I want to use the data which i declared in my controller
    int i = dbf.ExecuteSP("testproc", cmd);
    if (i >= 1)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

This is just a test data, my actual code is very large and the data which I want to insert is dynamic and not static.

Comment: What is the question here? You can just have a paramether in the `inserttestdata` (that no casing is killing me) and just pass the data from your controller? Of course you will have the make an instance of the class that contains the `inserttestdata` method inside your controller(or inject it).

Comment: @TeodorKurtev i am not able to make you understand,

i just want to pass the data from controller to modal, how can i do this?

Comment: You can create an object of the modal over here and simply assign all the data in that object and use it wherever you want to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where are you calling inserttestdata() from? You need to pass the testdata as a parameter to this method.

Here for example : `public bool inserttestdata(string testdata)`

then call `inserttestdata(testdata)`

Answer (score 0):

You can store data to model simply like this-

```
MyModel model = new MyModel();
model.someVariable = "your data";
```

Where your model would look like-

```
public class MyModel
{
    public string someVariable {get; set;}
}
```